# Why did the Deucalion lift off from underwater in the start of Season 2 in Aldnoah Zero?

Tags: aldnoah-zero

If I'm not mistaken, the Deucalion was stuck to the side of Saazbaum's landing castle right? How come on the Season 2 Episode 1 scene where Yuki rescued Inaho, they were underwater?

Comment: I'm assuming that Deucalion was hiding there.

Comment: But the reason they spearheaded Saazbaum's castle is because they were out of power so they instead aimed it at the castle to board it. I don't think they'd have any power left to even move from that position to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. It's because it was a jump cut. The moment Inaho touched the Aldnoah drive, it had a jump cut to the present time where the Deucalion was underwater because they are docked at the beach where we saw Inko and the rest of the girls in bikinis prior. So it was just a jump cut that wasn't very clearly executed.